# Block user account automatically if user doesn't verify his/her email within 24 hours of registration

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am working on a project using **symfony** and I need to track, wether user has verified his/her email withing the 24 hours of creating a new account.

How can I update the values in database automatically, so I can track this?

Comment: Add three fields: created date time, verified, disabled. Use a cron job to automatically disable any non-verified accounts that have been created over 24 hours ago.

Comment: Cron might be a bit of an overkill here.  You could just check when the user tries to login.  But it really depends on your code.  Your question simply does not have enough info.

Comment: I wouldn't even use Cron, I would just add a check to the login process that if the verification date is not within 24 hour of creation date, to prevent login. If you need to periodically delete accounts that have been blocked, add a feature to your admin dashboard to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a php script which check the unverified members, and if the date is greater than 24 hours, remove him.

Then just call your php script every hours or every days with a crontab.

**See "What is a crontab?"**
https://kb.iu.edu/d/afiz